# What does this error mean? C6001: using uninitialized memory 'Rect.'

Tags: c++, class, initialization, static-methods, member-functions

Visual Studio gave this bizzare error: C6001: using uninitialized memory 'Rect.'

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle
{public:
    int length, width;

    int Area(int length, int width)
    {
        return length * width;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Rectangle d1;
    d1.length = 5;
    d1.width = 10;

    cout << "d1 area=" << d1.length * d1.width << endl;

    Rectangle Rect;
    Rect.Area(Rect.length, Rect.width);

    return 0;
}
```

What is that mean and how to fix it?

Comment: What do you think is the current value of `Rect.length` ?

Comment: @HaveABlast What is  Dik?!

Comment: do I have to set them for another object too then?

Comment: maybe you mea `Rect.Alan(...` ?

Comment: You just call this function and throw away the result?

Comment: This isn't the code that gave that error. There is nothing named `Dik` here.

Comment: dik is a word from my native language, my fault. I updated the code.

Comment: Maybe the book is trying to teach you that the two Rectangle instances are independent objects that don't share values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object `Rect` declared in this declaration

```
Rectangle Rect;
```

has uninitialized data members `length` and `width`.

These uninitialized data members you are passing as arguments to the member function `Area`.

```
Rect.Area(Rect.legth, Rect.width);
```

So the call does not make a sense.

You could write for example

```
Rectangle Rect = { 5, 10 };
std::cout << Rect.Area(Rect.legth, Rect.width) << '\n';
```

Pay attention to that the function Area either should be a static member function or should use the data members `length` and `width` of the object.

That is either it should be declared like

```
static long long int Area(int length, int width)
{
    return static_cast<long long int>( length ) * width;
}
```

or like

```
long long int Area() const
{
    return static_cast<long long int>( length ) * width;
}
```

Comment: It also doesn't make sense anyway, since why pass the instance copies of its own members, which it already contains.

Comment: it was just a begginer book example question.

Comment: @HaveABlast especially examples for beginners should make sense. If the code in your question is from the book and the book does not explain that the code is non-sense then the book is not good